# Disable ViewPager swipe when swiping on a certain View

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to keep the swiping feature of my `ViewPager` however I want to disable it just when swiping on a certain `View` in my layout file (a custom `Preference` which I'm extending):

**activity.xml**

```
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
```

**activity.kt**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)
    viewpager.addOnPageChangeListener(this)
    // Initialise FragmentAdapter
    val fragmentAdapter = ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
    viewpager.adapter = fragmentAdapter
    viewpager.currentItem = 1
}


private inner class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm){
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when(position){
            0 -> {
                SettingsFragment()
            }
            2 -> {
                UserFragment()
            }
            else -> {
                MainFragment()
            }
        }
    }
    // 3 Fragments
    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 3
    }

}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Add Touch Listener on This view and `Return True` (Consume the event) .. i can only suggest this with this much Information in question .

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to achieve your goal.

```
class LockableViewPager : ViewPager {
    private var swipeable: Boolean = false

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {}

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
        this.swipeable = true
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return if (this.swipeable) {
            super.onTouchEvent(event)
        } else false
    }

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return if (this.swipeable) {
            super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event)
        } else false
    }

    fun setSwipeable(swipeable: Boolean) {
        this.swipeable = swipeable
    }
}
```

And then you just need to call

`setSwipeable(false)`

Hope this helps. Thank You